# Video.js work with vue-electron for video playlist

Tags: vue.js, electron, video.js

I am work on autoplay video playlist. I use glob to get all video absolute path from a target folder. My code is below:

```
let vm = this;
let trailerList = null;
trailerList = glob.sync(`${__static}/trailers/*.{mp4,flv,mov}`).map(path => {
    return {
        sources: [{ src: path }]
    };
});
let option = {
    autoplay: true,
    controls: false,
    muted: true
};

this.player = videojs(this.$refs.videoPlayer, option, () => {
    this.player.playlist(trailerList);
    this.player.playlist.autoadvance(0);
    this.player.playlist.repeat(true);
});
```

I got a `ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported`. It work if replace the variable `path` to `require("C:/.../static/trailers/Video.mp4")`. However, replace as `require(path)` will return module not found

Answer (score 0):

Just downgrade electron version to 5 and problem solve